# Unable to remove row in observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following in my viewmodel.    I want to remove a row from the view model when I hit a remove button.   The code executes the alert in the remove , but gives me an execution error on the actual remove.   I have tried, this.cartItem as well as ViewModel.cartItem.  I have spent hours trying to find a solution.  I think that my inexperience with the language keeps me from understanding the answers.  Please help.

```
this.cartItems = ko.mapping.fromJS(cartItems, mapping);

this.remove =function(){
    self = this;
    alert("self.title " + self.title());

    ViewModel.cartItems.remove(self);
    }\\ remove
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work but its easier to help if you create a fiddle

```
this.remove = function(data, event){
    var self = this;
    self.cartItems.remove(data);
}
```

Comment: Whenever I try to create a fiddle and click on the + under External Resources nothing happens.  the fiddles that I read attach knockout and the like there.  How should I fix this?   I have a fiddle account andd seem to be logged in.

Comment: I am putting up a fiddle that wont work because I don't know how to attach the knockout to it.   If you will guide me, it should show the problem.  I does on my environment.

Comment: If you want to add Knockout you just select it from the drop down under "Frameworks & Extensions" (a new fiddle has "No-Library (pure JS)" selected). IF you want to add KO and jQuery you would select one of those from the drop down and paste a link to the other in External Resources. You can find a link to just about any library here: http://cdnjs.com/